# How to convert ZIO[R, Nothing, Boolean] to UIO[Boolean]?

Tags: scala, zio

I just started learning ZIO and I'm having a difficult time finding the correct documentation. I obviously don't understand a core concept because this feels simple:

```
def getLastNameZio(firstName: String): URIO[R with ZMetrics with ZEnv, String] = {
  if (firstName == "bob") UIO("builder")
  else UIO("smith")
}

def isLastNameSmith(lastName: String): Boolean = {
  lastName == "smith"
}

def doWork(firstName: String): UIO[Boolean] = {
  for {
    lastName <- getLastNameZio(firstName)
    isSmithFamily = isLastNameSmith(lastName)
  } yield isSmithFamily // compiler complains
}
```

The compiler complains on that last line:

```
Required UIO [ Boolean ]
Found ZIO [ R, Nothing, Boolean ]
```

Why is this happening? I had to use for-comprehension otherwise the compiler will complain because `lastName` in `doWork` is a ZIO and can't just be inputted to `isLastNameSmith`

Answer (score 1):

Let's review the ZIO [type aliases](https://zio.dev/reference/core/zio/urio):

- `UIO[A]` = `ZIO[Any, Nothing, A]`
- `URIO[R, A]` = `ZIO[R, Nothing, A]`

The difference between the two being that one expects a `R` "context/requirement".

In your case, there's no reason for `getLastNameZio` to return a `URIO`, just stick with `UIO`.

Then a for comprehension like this can be just be written with a `.map(...)`:

```scala
getLastNameZio(firstName).map(isLastNameSmith)
```

---

In a case where the `URIO` would make sense, you would need to either:

- provide a `R` value right-away to get a `UIO` and then work with `UIO`s,
- or, "propagate" the `R` type so that `doWork` returns a `URIO`, and provide a `R` value later (usually only at the top level in the "main" class)

There's a few ways to provide a `R` value. One of them is via [`ZLayer`s](https://zio.dev/reference/di/dependency-injection-in-zio) with something that usually looks like the following:

```scala
theUrio.provides(layerProvidingRValue)
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I had the wrong code there. I updated `URIO[String]` to `URIO[R with ZMetrics with ZEnv]`. I'm still getting the same compile error (tried your map solution as well)

Comment: I think a concept I don't understand is what `R` is supposed to be in this case. I understand it's essentially "Requirement" where the effect cannot be run until all the requirements are met. But in this case, what is it expecting for `R` when it complains that I'm providing `ZIO[R, Nothing, Boolean`? My code doesn't need the environment here right? I just want to return `UIO`

Comment: Yes, just type the method as `UIO[String]`. You are right: it doesn't require anything.

Comment: `R` will make sense when you compose "services" together in a Dependency Injection way (that's not the only use case but the main one).

Comment: Let's say I wanted to keep it as `URIO`, is there any way to solve my original problem without changing `getLastNameZio` to return `UIO`?

Comment: Updated my answer.